# cannot declare Timer globally in Azure Bot

Tags: c#, timer, botframework

I'm using .NET Bot Builder v 3.15.2.2 and testing it out in Bot Emulator v 3.5.36

I'm trying to apply a timer (quite similar to [#837](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/837) ) where after a new conversation has been started, there's a timer of 10minutes to check for any inactivity. Once its already lapsed, it will post a message to the conversation, if someone join the conversation it will stop the timer. I tried a simple way, by declaring a timer globally and having a timer callback. But I always receive in the emulator even before I could type anything: "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue". If I remove the Timer as a global variable, its running okay. I know that for classes I wanted to be declared globally, it should be serializable, but I'm not sure how it applies to others like the Timer.

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result) {

     var message = await result;
     await SaveConversation(context, message);

     var timerCallBack = new TimerCallback(this.TimerEventCallback);
     this.botTimer = new Timer(timerCallBack, context, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0).Milliseconds, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0).Milliseconds);
    }


public void TimerEventCallback(object obj)
    {
         var context = (IDialogContext)obj;
        Activity reply = (Activity)context.Activity;

        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(reply.ServiceUrl));
        connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply.CreateReply($"Conversation has been closed due to Inactivity")).Wait();
        this.botTimer.Dispose();
    }`
```

Comment: Timers are not serializable.  You could add a static ConcurrentDictionary of timers, keyed on ConversationId ... when the timer is created, add it to the dictionary and remove it once it is finished firing.

Answer (score 7):

> "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue"

If you check the error log in Bot Emulator, the exception: `"Type 'System.Threading.Timer' in xxxxxxxx is not marked as serializable. "` is thrown, which cause the issue.

> after a new conversation has been started, there's a timer of 10minutes to check for any inactivity. Once its already lapsed, it will post a message to the conversation, if someone join the conversation it will stop the timer.

You can try this approach to achieve your requirement: collect some information from the current conversation and store it in a scheduled message (specify [ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc)) in Azure service bus queue, and then you can use service bus queue triggered Azure Functions or Azure WebJobs to handle queue message and send proactive message.

To stop sending proactive message for a specific scheduled message, you can cancel that specific scheduled message by calling [CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.cancelscheduledmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_CancelScheduledMessageAsync_System_Int64_).

Comment: Thank you for the suggested. Though I was able to found out I can set the Timer as [NonSerialized] for me to be able to declare it globally in the RootDialog without the Bot throwing out an error. 


 [NonSerialized]
public Timer botTimer;

but thank you!